# Mapbox fitbounds option not working only Android, works in IOS

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, fitbounds

I am using Mapboxgl for React Native project.
And I have trouble with fitbounds function

It works well on IOS but not working on Android, it shows whole world map always. This is my code

```
import MapboxGL from '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl';

export default class App extends Component {


  captureRef = (map) => {
    this.zoomToBounds(map)
  }

  async zoomToBounds(map) {
    const _ = await map.getCenter()
    map.fitBounds(bound[0], bound[1], 0, 0) //it work on IOS
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={this.captureRef}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am not sure why it works well on IOS but not working in Android.
Thanks